# Can't find some apps in Play Store while others don't work

Tags: google-play-store, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-4

After I factory reset my Samsung Galaxy S4, some apps were reinstalled easily, while others didn't work as they used, and some can't be found in Play Store (YouTube Downloader). All Music Downloader won't work. I had Simple MP3 Downloader before, now it doesn't work.

Why can't I find them anymore, and why some of them also don't work anymore?

Comment: Some apps may be restricted to some countries, or they may have been removed by Google. Try to browse Play Store using browser to confirm if the apps are still there. Regarding "music downloader won't work", it's unclear what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

TubeMate (and all similar YouTube video downloaders) were removed from the Play Store for violating Google's Terms and Conditions. Simple MP3 Downloader was also removed for this reason. You probably downloaded the apps before they were removed from the Play Store, so that is why you had them before.

You can still install those two apps to your phone from manually installing the .apk files for [TubeMate](http://tubemate.net/) and [Simple MP3 Downloader](http://simple-mp3-downloader.en.softonic.com/android).